# Disambiguate the [builtin] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the [builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtin) tag for?

I tried looking at some of the questions, but they appear to be all over the place. Some are about the `__builtin_*` macros in C compilers, some are related to shell built-ins, some are about Python, etc.

Comment: It does not have a tag wiki, so it is not officially for anything yet.

Answer (score 2):

[builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtin), [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in) and [builtins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtins) are used pretty much indifferently and should be merged.

I don't see any value in splitting the tag. While “builtin” has a different technical meaning in different languages, the core concept follows the same idea. Requiring that all [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) questions use [shell-builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell-builtin) rather than [builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtin) isn't particularly useful.

Perhaps these tags should be removed altogether — I don't see any value in subscribing to or ignoring [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in). Nonetheless, they do have some use in a search, which argues for keeping them.